# Máximo registro por año

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una tabla con registros como estos:

```
CODIGOEMPLEADO   FECHAINICIO
0001             02/10/2009
0001             03/10/2009 
0002             13/11/2010
0002             14/11/2010
0002             15/11/2010
0003             03/12/2010
0003             04/12/2010
0003             05/12/2010
0004             01/12/2010           
0004             02/12/2010
0004             03/12/2010
0001             02/10/2011
0001             03/10/2011
0002             13/11/2011
0002             14/11/2011
0002             15/11/2011
0003             03/12/2011
0003             04/12/2011
0003             05/12/2011
0004             01/12/2011           
0004             02/12/2011
0004             03/12/2011
0001             02/10/2012
0001             03/10/2012
0002             13/11/2012
0002             14/11/2012
0002             15/11/2012
0003             03/12/2012
0003             04/12/2012
0003             05/12/2012
0004             01/12/2012           
0004             02/12/2012
0004             03/12/2012
```

Necesito sacar el mayor registro con la mayor fecha de cada empleado por año(mayor a 2010), lo que daría por resultado esto.

```
CODIGOEMPLEADO   FECHAINICIO
0002             15/11/2010
0003             05/12/2010
0004             03/12/2010
0001             03/10/2011
0002             15/11/2011
0003             05/12/2011
0004             03/12/2011
0001             03/10/2012
0002             15/11/2012
0003             05/12/2012
0004             03/12/2012
```

No tengo muchos conocimientos en sub-consultas, entonces leyendo creo que puede ser algo así *(aunque solo me traerá el máximo de todos los años y no por cada año por empleado)*:

```
SELECT CODIGOEMPLEADO,FECHAINICIO WHERE FECHAINICIO IN (SELECT MAX(FECHAINICIO) FROM DETALLE C WHERE C.CODIGOEMPLEADO = CODIGOEMPLEADO)

FROM DETALLE

WHERE FECHAINI > TO_DATE('01/01/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

---

Gracias por la ayuda. Efectivamente así funciona la consulta, pero al momento de traer mas campos se complica un poco la cosa, esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT e.CODIGOEM AS "NUM. DOCUMENTO",e.NOMBRE1||' '||TRIM(e.NOMBRE2)||' '||e.APELLIDO1||' '||e.APELLIDO2 "NOMBRE",MAX(TO_CHAR(vd.FECHAINI,'DD/MM/YYYY')),nc.TIPOCONTRATO

FROM EMPLEADO e,VINCULACION v,VINCULACIONDET vd,TIPOCONTRATO nc

WHERE e.CODEMPLEADO = v.CODEMPLEADO AND v.NUMVINCULACION = vd.NUMVINCULACION AND vd.CODTIPOCONTRATO = nc.CODTIPOCONTRATO AND vd.FECHAINI >= DATE '2010-01-01'

GROUP BY e.CODEMPLEADO,e.NOMBRE1,e.NOMBRE2,e.APELLIDO1,e.APELLIDO2,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM vd.FECHAINI),nc.TIPOCONTRATO
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
CODIGOEM   NOMBRE         FECHAINI    TIPOCONTRATO
444444     PEDRO PEREZ    24/08/16    Periodo de Prueba
444444     PEDRO PEREZ    07/02/17    Propiedad
444444     PEDRO PEREZ    01/01/17    Periodo de Prueba
```

salen 2 registros del 2017 cuando solo necesito 1, el de fecha máxima, entonces el TIPOCONTRATO como tiene valores diferentes por eso trae dos registros, como hago para solucionar esto  aun cuando necesito seguir trayendo mas campos con valores diferentes.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el SQL que has intentado por favor?

Comment: SELECT CODIGOEMPLEADO,FECHAINICIO WHERE FECHAINICIO IN (SELECT MAX(FECHAINICIO) FROM DETALLE C WHERE C.CODIGOEMPLEADO = CODIGOEMPLEADO)

    FROM DETALLE

    WHERE FECHAINI > TO_DATE('01/01/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No necesitas subconsultas en este caso. Lo que necesitas es agrupar por `CODIGOEMPLEADO` y por año. Entonces puedes usar `MAX(FECHAINICIO)` para obtener el resultado deseado:

```
select codigoempleado, max(fechainicio)
  from detalle
 where fechainicio >= date '2010-01-01'
 group by codigoempleado, extract(year from fechainicio)
```

**Edición**

Si necesitas otros campos relacionados a ese mismo registro con la máxima fecha, entonces usar `GROUP BY` + `MAX` no funcionará. Mas bien, lo que conviene en este caso es usar la función ventana `ROW_NUMBER()`. Notarás que la lógica del `GROUP BY` pasa a la claúsula `PARTITION BY`, y el `MAX(fechainicio)` pasa a la claúsula `ORDER BY`. Usando esta función, identificamos los registros deseados con `WHERE rn = 1`:

```
SELECT CODIGOEM AS "NUM. DOCUMENTO",
       NOMBRE1||' '||TRIM(NOMBRE2)||' '||APELLIDO1||' '||APELLIDO2 AS "NOMBRE",
       TO_CHAR(FECHAINI,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
       TIPOCONTRATO
  FROM (
    SELECT e.CODIGOEM,
           e.NOMBRE1,
           e.NOMBRE2,
           e.APELLIDO1,
           e.APELLIDO2,
           vd.FECHAINI,
           nc.TIPOCONTRATO,
           row_number() over (
             partition by e.CODIGOEM, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM vd.FECHAINI)
                 order by vd.FECHAINI desc) as rn
    FROM EMPLEADO e,VINCULACION v,VINCULACIONDET vd,TIPOCONTRATO nc
    WHERE e.CODEMPLEADO = v.CODEMPLEADO
      AND v.NUMVINCULACION = vd.NUMVINCULACION
      AND vd.CODTIPOCONTRATO = nc.CODTIPOCONTRATO
      AND vd.FECHAINI >= DATE '2010-01-01'
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Nota adicional: Valdría la pena modificar la consulta para usar joins explícitos en vez de joins implícitos. Es mucho más fácil entender y mantener la consulta de esa manera.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, me ha ayudado mucho, aunque edite la pregunta porque me surgió otro inconveniente

Comment: Entonces tendrás que usar `ROW_NUMBER()` para resolver este problema. Modifiqué la respuesta.

Comment: excelente, ya la termine y le agregue los otros campos, funciona a la perfección, quedo muy agradecido con tu ayuda y bueno tarea de vacaciones leer mucho de oracle =D